# Node.js: how to deal with getFullYear in pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to get the lifeSpan by subtracting dateOfBirth from dateOfDeath. getFullYear() is returning the year in console. But, in pug.. it is throwing error as follows: `Cannot read property 'getFullYear' of undefined`

Author Schema for lifeSpan:

```
AuthorSchema
.virtual('lifeSpan')
.get(function() {
    const lifeSpan = (this.dateOfDeath.getFullYear() - this.dateOfBirth.getFullYear()).toString();
    return lifeSpan;
});
```

Author Controller:

```
exports.authorList = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await Author.find({}).exec((error, authorList) => {
            if(error) return authorList;

            // console.log(authorList);

            res.render('./author/index', { title: 'Author List', authorList: authorList});
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

Index.pug:

```
ul
    each author in authorList
      li 
        a(href=author.url) #{author.name}
        |  (#{author.lifeSpan})

    else
      li There is No Author in The List.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show me your console log result that you are mentioning is correct

Comment: Sorry for being late. Console is showing as following:
```43```
```38``` As, i have added dateOfBirth and dateOfDeath in 2 collection. Values are showing in different line.

Comment: It seems like PUG overrides "this", and while the getter of virtual is called at runtime, "this" is referring to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like PUG overrides "this", and while the getter of the virtual field is called at runtime, "this" is referring to something else.

So as a solution try this, add a PUG function like:

```
- function getLifeSpan(author){ return author.lifeSpan; }
```

so that your pug file looks like this:

```
- function getLifeSpan(author){ return author.lifeSpan; }
ul
    each author in authorList
      li 
        a(href=author.url) #{author.name}
        |  (#{getLifeSpan(author)})

    else
      li There is No Author in The List.
```

Comment: That works! can you please take a look on the following question? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577089/node-js-success-message-is-not-showing)